# Menu Structure in $rootScope doesn't update view

Tags: angularjs

I'm new to angular and I try to get a submenu working. In each Controller, I use the $rootScope to apply the actual Submenu of the view. The Menu is shown, but it doesn't update on view change:

DashboardController:

```
controller('DashboardCtrl', function DashboardCtrl ( $scope , $rootScope, restService, $location, $routeParams) {
    $rootScope.submenu = [{
        name: "link1",
        link: "/#/link1"
    },{
        name: "link2",
        link: "/#/link2"
    }];
});
```

ArticleController:

```
controller('ArticleCtrl', function ArticleCtrl ( $scope , $rootScope, restService, $location, $routeParams) {
    $rootScope.submenu = [{
        name: "link1",
        link: "/#/link1"
    },{
        name: "link2",
        link: "/#/link2"
    }];
});
```

I think I miss something. Could anybody show me a working solution?

Thanks

Comment: rarely need to add  your model data directly to $rootscope...use $scope

Comment: Well, the two submenus you posted are completely identical, so I'm not surprised nothing changes. Post a working plunkr.